# Expected moves per turn when some rolls lose a turn

Tags: probability

I am working on a game where pieces move based on the roll of a die. Each piece moves differently in response to a die roll, some always move a single space, some move 3 spaces at a time but only on a roll of 5 or 6 etc. Overall each piece has an average movement of one space per roll, which is usually straightforward to calculate. The problem arises with the new moveset I'm thinking of and trying to calculate the expected movement per roll.

The new piece moves as follows: On a roll of 4, 5 or 6 the piece moves 3 spaces. On a roll of 1, 2 or 3 the piece does not move and completely ignores the next roll (a roll of 1, 1, 4 will result in a total movement of 3 spaces). How do you calculate the average movement per roll in this case? I'm unsure of how to factor in the cases where the next roll is ignored.

I have thrown together simulator in python which shows the above moveset does result in an average of 1 space per turn. However I would like to understand the underlying math so I can more easily play around with different configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An average movement of one space per roll is correct.

Let me write $H$ for a high roll ($4,5,6$) and $L$ for a low roll ($1,2,3$). Assuming the game has been going on for a long time, your piece will advance on the current roll in the following situations:

$HH$: Your currect (time $t$) and previous (time $t-1$) rolls were high.
$HLLH$: Roll $t$ is high; rolls $t-1,t-1$ were low; roll $t-2$ was high.
$HLLLLH,\ HLLLLLLH,$ and so on: your current roll is high, and is separated from the last high roll by an even number of low rolls.

So the probability that your piece will advance on the current turn is given by the infinite geometric series:
$$\frac14+\frac1{16}+\frac1{64}+\cdots=\frac13$$
and the average number of spaces moved is $\frac13\cdot3=1.$

Actually, this calculation is correct only if the game has been going on forever; the exact probability of advancing is $\frac12$ on the first turn, $\frac14$ on the second turn, $\frac38$ on the third turn, and so on. However, as time goes by, the error in using the infinite series approaches zero.

Comment: So for generalizing this for different patterns, if a loss of the turn has a probability p of not happening then the series would be $$\frac1{p^2}+\frac1{p^4}+\frac1{p^6}+\cdots=\frac1{1-p^2}-1$$ for the probability of being able to move on a given roll?

Comment: That can't be right; note that $\frac1{1-p^2}-1$ becomes arbitrarily large (so it's not a probability) when $p$ gets close to $1.$ With a probability $p$ of not losing a turn, and so a probability $q=1-p$ of losing a turn, I think the correct (limiting) probability of getting to move on a given turn is $$p^2+p^2q^2+p^2q^4+\dots=\frac{p^2}{1-q^2}=\frac p{2-p}.$$

Comment: right, should have seen it was unbounded, got myself mixed up a little as both probabilities were the same (also shouldn't be reciprocals of p in my sum). Regardless you have thoroughly answered my question, I'll give it some time and mark accepted barring some extra super answer coming through